# MySQL CASE WHEN numb IS NULL ignore record WHERE numb IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, min

I have these data in a table:

```
numb    m   value
8070    1   7.63
NULL    1   7.64
NULL    1   7.65
8070    2   7.939
8070    2   7.935
8070    2   7.941
NULL    3   7.62
8070    4   7.92
8070    4   7.935
```

I need `MIN(value)` and `MAX(value)` for each `m`, and if there is a `value` without `numb` (NULL), then the ones **with** a `numb` should be ignored.

So I should be getting the following results:

```
numb    m   value
NULL    1   7.64
NULL    1   7.65
8070    2   7.935
8070    2   7.941
NULL    3   7.62
8070    4   7.92
8070    4   7.935
```

I've tried quite a lot of different things, but nothing seems to work, and I have no more ideas how to find relevant info. Can you please point me to the right direction?

UPDATE:
to get the number of values it looks like this:

```
COALESCE(
IF(
  COUNT(
    CASE
      WHEN m IN (2, 4)
      THEN value
      ELSE
      CASE
        WHEN m IN (1, 3) AND numb IS NULL
        THEN value
      END
    END
  ) = 0,
  NULL,
  COUNT(
    CASE
      WHEN m IN (2, 4)
      THEN value
      ELSE
      CASE
        WHEN m IN (1, 3) AND numb IS NULL
        THEN value
      END
    END
  )
),
COUNT(
  CASE
    WHEN m IN (1, 3)
    AND numb IS NOT NULL
    THEN value
  END
)
) AS cnt
```

Comment: Do you care about the `numb` values?

Comment: How do you mean exactly?

Comment: Do you need the `MIN` and `MAX` dependent on the value of `numb` as well as the value of `m` e.g. if there are 2 different values of `numb` say 8070 and 9402 does that make a difference to the result? and do you need to get the value of `numb` associated with the `MIN`  and `MAX` values?

Comment: yes, I need `m` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It has two levels of nested derived tables. The first:

```
SELECT m,
       MIN(CASE WHEN numb IS NULL THEN value END) AS min_null,
       MAX(CASE WHEN numb IS NULL THEN value END) AS max_null,
       MIN(CASE WHEN numb IS NOT NULL THEN value END) AS min_normal,
       MAX(CASE WHEN numb IS NOT NULL THEN value END) AS max_normal
FROM numbers
GROUP BY m;
```

computes the minimum and maximum values for each value of `m`, dependent on whether `numb` was a number or `NULL`. In the next level,

```
SELECT m,
       COALESCE(min_null, min_normal) AS min_value,
       COALESCE(max_null, max_normal) AS max_value
FROM (... query 1...)
```

we use compute the appropriate minimum and maximum values to use (if there was a `NULL` value, we use that, otherwise we use the one associated with numeric values of `numb`). Finally we `JOIN` the numbers table to the result of query 2 to find the appropriate values of `numb` for each value of `m`:

```
SELECT n.numb, n.m, n.value
FROM numbers n
JOIN (... query 2 ...) num ON num.m = n.m AND (num.min_value = n.value OR num.max_value = n.value)
ORDER BY n.m, n.value
```

Output:

```
numb    m   value
null    1   7.64
null    1   7.65
8070    2   7.935
8070    2   7.941
null    3   7.62
8070    4   7.92
8070    4   7.935
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gSfvz27taiG9Jtbik6mVgU/0)

The full query:

```
SELECT n.numb, n.m, n.value
FROM numbers n
JOIN (SELECT m,
             COALESCE(min_null, min_normal) AS min_value,
             COALESCE(max_null, max_normal) AS max_value
      FROM (SELECT m,
                   MIN(CASE WHEN numb IS NULL THEN value END) AS min_null,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN numb IS NULL THEN value END) AS max_null,
                   MIN(CASE WHEN numb IS NOT NULL THEN value END) AS min_normal,
                   MAX(CASE WHEN numb IS NOT NULL THEN value END) AS max_normal
            FROM numbers
            GROUP BY m) n) num ON num.m = n.m AND (num.min_value = n.value OR num.max_value = n.value)
ORDER BY n.m, n.value
```

Comment: Many thanks! I was also trying with `COALESCE` but I couldn't figure it out. It is actually possible to do it like this also: `SELECT m,
       COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN numb IS NULL THEN value END), MIN(CASE WHEN numb IS NOT NULL THEN value END)) AS min_value,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN numb IS NULL THEN value END), MAX(CASE WHEN numb IS NOT NULL THEN value END)) AS max_value
FROM numbers
GROUP BY m;` is it?

Comment: @user2511599 if you mean the inner query, yes, I wrote it the way I did mainly because that's how I developed the solution, from the bottom up, and then I didn't rewrite it because it was a bit easier to read and understand the way it was.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I count the number of values?

Comment: @user2511599 which values do you want to count?

Comment: `value` values :)

Comment: I have figured it out!